# LinkButton in update panel does not even fire client side event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I have a page that if IsPostBack is true, calls a javascript function which gets the size of the screen, passes the width and height to hidden fields and clicks a button to cause a PostBack. So I can retrieve the size of the user's screen and then load the page with default data with tables the right size etc.

Invariably, when the page (having posted back once) displays the data, a gridview is populated. Each row has a 'delete' Link Button in it. Each Link Button is set OnClientClick to call a javascript function to confirm you want to delete.

Above the grid is a row of text boxes / buttons / dropdownlists which allow you to search for, or filter the data showing. The Gridview is in an update panel. When the page first loads its data, and shows the list of projects, the delete Link Buttons all work okay. In every row, no problem. The Confirm box is displayed and, if Okay is selected, the asynchronous postback occurs.

If, after the initial data is displayed (which is already after one postback) you then use the search box and button, or use a dropdownlist to filter the data (the Search button and filter DropDownList are async triggers for the UpdatePanel) the data refreshes okay (always) but, then, sometimes, the 'delete' LinkButton in each row of the GridView does nothing. It doesn't even fire the ClientSide function. It's as if it is dead.

I had a similar problem a while ago with ImageButtons and the received wisdom seems to be 'change them to LinkButtons'. But I have dozens of grids with 'delete' LinkButtons that work okay, but this one has decided to stop working - sometimes.

I have to say, since moving to Framework 4.0, I'm thinking of giving up on UpdatePanels. Seem to have nothing but problems with sites that worked reliably for years in Framework 2.0

Any ideas please? Is this anything to do with the order in which controls are loaded on the second postbacks?

Edit: There is a twist to this. When this situation occurs, i.e. clicking on the Delete link does not even trigger the Client Side event - if you click on an area of the page outside the Gridview (i.e. outside the UpdatePanel) - and then click back on the Delete link - it works!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ImageButtons: There is a bug with IE10: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position ( http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx ). Just upgrade to .NET 4.5.

Regarding LinkButtons: Do you have "ID" property? I remember I had a similar issue because my linkButton didn't have an ID.

Could you post some code? It would help.